# Extend interface with multiple imported interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have following scenario. I have multiple interfaces that i import like:

```
import * as typeDefTypes from "../graphSchemas/generatedTypes"
```

Now i want to extend another interface with all that interfaces inside of them.

My try was to use spread operator but this indeed does not work:

```
interface ResolverInterface {
   ...typeDefTypes
}
```

I mean i could to it like:

```
interface ResolverInterface extends typeDefTypes.Book, typeDefTypes.User ... {}
```

but this is not what i want since there are alot of interfaces

Comment: Can you show us how `generatedTypes` looks like? Does it contain multiple `export interface <InterfaceName>` exports?

Comment: @eol yes, there are multiple named exports like `export interface book {}`, `export interface User {...}` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the so called [re-export](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#re-exports) of a bundled interface. This allows you to do the following:

```
// in your resolver-interface.ts
export * from '../graphSchemas/generatedTypes';
export interface CustomInterface {
    customField: string
}

// in your main.ts
import * as ResolverInterface from './resolver-interface';
let a:ResolverInterface.CustomInterface =  { ... }
let b:ResolverInterface.Book = { ... }
```